Trying to identity a movie about stealing a briefcase
I am trying to remember the name of a Hollywood movie which I watched very early around 10 year ago. This movie is made around year 2000 +/- 5. If I can say the the category could be Action/Suspense.
Story line: The whole movie is based on one briefcase(silver colored metal as far as I can recall). It is like there is a gang of people who want to transport the briefcase to some people or to some group. Till the end of movie, no-body knew what was inside that briefcase and it was never shown in the movie. Another scene, There was a Russian dancer in the movie and someone shoots her while she was dancing.

Aha, Ronin (1998) fits the bill,

Ronin is the Japanese word used for Samurai without a master. In this case, the Ronin are outcast specialists of every kind, whose services are available to everyone - for money. Dierdre (undoubtedly from Ireland) hires several Ronin to form a team in order to retrieve an important suitcase from a man who is about to sell it to the Russians. After the mission has been completed successfully, the suitcase immediately gets switched by a member of the team who seems to work into his own pocket. The complex net of everyone tricking everyone begins to surface slowly, and deadly...





